# Flash apps integration in android app

Tags: android, flash, flash-builder, integration, flash-cs5

Hey friends i am new to android using flash,so i need to know how can we integrate or code a flash program into my android app.I would like to see a source code for reference if anyone has done coding in android containing flash into it, please help me by sharing your source code.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about integrating a Flash program into an Android app, persay, as it purely depends on what platform the Android app is built on. Flash Player is, itself, primarily for web, although they can also operate on desktops via a Flash Projector.

I do know you can build Android apps using Adobe AIR 3, which uses Flash and AS3. I would look into that.